# Insert multiple checked values from gridview into Database

Tags: sql, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, insert

I have this methode to loop through if the data in my gridview is checked or not, if they are checked they should be inserted into the database.
As you can see the only data I want to insert from the gridview is the text from cell[2] in the gridview and it's in the name of **@HeaderName**

```
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("my con string"))
        {
            con.Open();
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewConsNames.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox myCheckBox = row.FindControl("myCheckBox") as CheckBox;
                if (myCheckBox.Checked)
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Accounting_Consolidation_ServiceOutputs(Cusomer_Name, Service_Name, Header_Name, Sort_Postion, Rename_to, Value) Values(@CustName,@ServiceName,@HeaderName,@Sort,@Rename,@Value)", con))
                    {
                        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PersonId", Convert.ToInt32(GridViewConsNames.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value));
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustName", TextBoxCustName.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServiceName", DropDownListServicesAvailable2.SelectedItem.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HeaderName", "Name of the checked cells from my gridview");
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sort", null);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rename", "");
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", null);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I have tried with this

```
 GridViewRow row = GridViewConsNames.SelectedRow; 
 string headername = row.Cells[2].Text;
```

But this seems not working

Comment: Explode? you can look at the AddWithValue = @HeaderName I need to put it there, it does not work because I just realized the gridview.slected row does not work since there are no rows selected and they are all selected through the checkbox instead

Comment: What is the _"Name of the checked cells from my gridview"_? Do you really want to insert the  `Text` property of those checkboxes? If so, why haven't you used `myCheckBox.Text`?

Comment: Because the check box and text next to it are in 2 different cells but on the same row. So Basically, just check the names I want and them insert them to the table, just missing the headerName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use `GridViewRow row = GridViewConsNames.SelectedRow` when you actually want to use all rows where the checkbox is selected?

So i guess that this is what you want:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewConsNames.Rows)
{
    CheckBox myCheckBox = row.FindControl("myCheckBox") as CheckBox;
    if (myCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        // ...
            string headerName = row.Cells[2].Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HeaderName", headerName);
        // ...
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi man sorry for my late answer, I solved it by looking at your method with small changes, but it was right! Thank u so much for the help